# Concatenating phpexcel chart DataSeriesValues

Tags: charts, phpexcel

I'm creating a chart in phpexcel, and for my plotcategory i have the following code:

```
$xAxisLabel=array(new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues('String', 'report!$A$2:$A$' . count($data), NULL, $itemCount));
```

So the x-axis labels are the values from the A2-A... records.

[image]

This i works like it should. However, i would like to add the values from The B records to, so instead of the labels being March, February, January .....

I would like them to be March 2014, February 2014, January 2015, ...

How can i achieve this? And if anyone has an answer, can you explain how you found it? I can't find any documentation about the chart capabilities in phpExcel at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a concatenation, but try

```
$xAxisLabel=array(
    new PHPExcel_Chart_DataSeriesValues(
        'String', 'report!$A$2:$B$' . count($data), NULL, $itemCount
    )
);
```

for nested Month/Year